# why doesnt my html video work neither if it is a youtube link(like in this case) nor if i use mp4?

Tags: html

i am trying to include a video into my html project, but when i run the code, the video doesnt work. what is the problem?

```
    <video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rt-2cxAiPJk" controls width="400px"></video>
<video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VYb3B1ETlk&t=1s" controls width="400px"></video>
<video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_me3xsvDgk&t=1s" controls width="400px"></video>
```

Comment: You should run it with web-server. What kind of ide do you use?

Comment: @DimaVak vscode

Answer (score 1):

I think the `src` is expecting to find a file on your machine, or possibly you can't play a video from a different domain. I'm not sure what the exact requirements are for `src` but it's probably a domain issue.

YouTube does provide embed code for videos and they use an iframe to make them work. I tested on my machine and with the iframe it works. For your first video it's

```
<iframe width="857" height="482" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rt-2cxAiPJk" 
    title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" 
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
           encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

You can probably just copy that for every video and change the src.

You can right-click a video on YouTube to get the embed code.

Comment: P.S. You don't need `px` for the width and height.